# XML parsing using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to parse the XML below,  however the values generated is wrong. Anyone has an idea?

Results

```
Code                  Pay1_515
    5570, Industry1, 1     10
    5570, Industry2, 2     10
```

Sample XML

```
 DECLARE @XML xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CookedData>
      <Column DestinationColumnCode="Code">
        <r v="5570, Industry1, 1" />
        <r v="5570, Industry2, 2" />
      </Column>
      <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_515">
        <r v="10" />
        <r v="10" />
      </Column>
    </CookedData>';
```

Sample code

```
with C as
(
  select T.X.value('(Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Code"]/r/@v)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(3000)') as Code,
         T.X.value('(Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_515"]/r/@v)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(3000)') as Pay
  from @XML.nodes('/CookedData/Column') as T(X)
)
SELECT * FROM C
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with C as
(
  select T.X.value('(//Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Code"]/r/@v)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(3000)') as Code,
         T.X.value('(//Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_515"]/r/@v)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(3000)') as Pay
  from @XML.nodes('/CookedData/Column') as T(X)
```

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan I tried the code , however the result is wrong.

Comment: How do you want to correspond the values of attributes `@v` from one column to another?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
SELECT
    Code = T.X.value('@DestinationColumnCode', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
    RValue= r.value('@v', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('/CookedData/Column') as T(X)
CROSS APPLY
    X.nodes('r') AS T2(R)
```

This will produce the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has been bugging me all morning. I wondered if I could improve on the answer given by @marc_s (to the detriment of my actual work :-/) and I have managed to get the required output. However, some caveats:

1. This assumes that the order of child `r` nodes in each `Column` node correlates to the other (i.e. the first `r` node in each should be side by side and so on). This is because there is no other way to tie them together that I can see.
2. It's not very generic - as it stands, it won't work for *n* columns without extra code and fiddling about.
3. You don't mind some pretty filthy code which is likely to be pretty poor performing on large amounts of data (even with some tuning - my brain has now melted and can't cope with any more fiddling on it).
4. I've tested with a few more rows in the XML but I would not guarantee it's efficacy in all cases, it would need some serious testing.
5. I couldn't be bothered to get the final column names right.

Someone, anyone, please feel free to improve this, but FWIW here it is (complete, working code):

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CookedData>
      <Column DestinationColumnCode="Code">
        <r v="5570, Industry1, 1" />
        <r v="5570, Industry2, 2" />
      </Column>
      <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_515">
        <r v="10" />
        <r v="10" />
      </Column>
    </CookedData>';

DECLARE @shredXML TABLE (Code VARCHAR(10), RValue VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @Codes TABLE (RowNum INT, ColCode VARCHAR(10))

--Do this once at the start and use the results.
INSERT INTO @shredXML
SELECT 
    Code = T.X.value('@DestinationColumnCode', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
    RValue= r.value('@v', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('/CookedData/Column') as T(X)
CROSS APPLY
    X.nodes('r') AS T2(R)


--First get the distinct list of DestinationColumnCode values.
INSERT INTO @Codes
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colcodes.Code), colcodes.Code 
FROM @shredXML colcodes 
GROUP BY colcodes.Code


SELECT p1.RValue, p2.RValue 
FROM (
    --Get all the values for the code column
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Codes.RValue) AS RowNum, Codes.RValue, Codes.Code
    FROM (
            SELECT x.Code, x.RValue FROM @shredXML x
            INNER JOIN @Codes c
                ON c.ColCode = x.Code
            WHERE c.RowNum = 1) AS Codes) AS p1
--Join the values column on RowNum
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Vals.RValue) AS RowNum, Vals.RValue, Vals.Code
            FROM (
            SELECT x.Code, x.RValue FROM @shredXML x
            INNER JOIN @Codes c
                ON c.ColCode = x.Code
            WHERE c.RowNum = 2) AS Vals) AS p2
    ON p1.RowNum = p2.RowNum
```

## EDIT

Finally got SQLFiddle to play ball and run [the example above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d789/5)